# [Flutter/Riverpod]difference between .future and .value

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I would like to know the difference between the two followings;

- `ref.watch(fooProvider).value` returns `String?`
- `ref.watch(fooProvider.future)` returns `Future<String?>`

The difference is only what they return?

I want to know when to use. Please give me example.

below is a sample code;

```dart
final fooProvider = FutureProvider<String?>((ref) {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => "foo");
});

final xxx = FutureProvider<String?>((ref) async {
  final String? ttt = ref.watch(fooProvider).value;
  final String? sss = await ref.watch(fooProvider.future);

  return '$ttt / $sss';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> ref.watch(fooProvider.future);

Is a Future<String?>

> ref.watch(fooProvider).value;

Is a String? so needless to await.